# Get Current Thread Handle

Tags: multithreading, delphi, handle

I have problem in Delphi application with determining current application (current Thread) handle. I know that I can get Current Thread ID with Windows API function `GetCurrentThreadID`, but I need current Thread handle to use as param for another Windows API function that is SuspendThread.

Actually what I am trying to do is to make one of my old dll's made for hooking API functions located in kernel32.dll like `OpenProcess` or `TerminateProcess`to also do hook for `SuspendProcess`. Hook is located in dll file and using SetWindowsHookEx to be injected in running processes then finding base address of target functions. 
I had no problem with hooking functions like TerminateProcess because it needs process ID as param that is easy to obtain in main application using `GetCurrentProcessID`. To make similar hook for `SuspendThread` function i need to pass thread handle as param.

Only place where I found thread handle is `PROCESS_INFORMATION` structure that contains

```
typedef struct _PROCESS_INFORMATION { // pi  
    HANDLE hProcess; 
    HANDLE hThread; 
    DWORD dwProcessId; 
    DWORD dwThreadId; 
} PROCESS_INFORMATION;
```

but problem is that this structure is available only after creating process with `CreateProcess` API function. Main goal is to prevent program users to use different tools available online like ProcessExplorer etc to terminate process. I acheived that with success hooking TerminateProcess API calls and preventing that way closing my app but Suspend option in those process exploring tools can Suspend my process. It is internet kiosk application and it is vital that users can't close that application. Applications is currently running in Windows XP and it has to be run on administrator account because other apps that users are using after logging in my application requires administrator account to operate, so I can't simply run my application under restricted user.

Is there any way that I can get my main application main thread handle in Delphi ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If a user is able to install programs (such as Process Explorer) on your Internet kiosk, you have already lost the game. You should be asking how to lock down the entire computer with stuff like group policy.

Comment: I would inspect what applications are doing exactly that requires "administrator" rights and if that is a limited enough subset of privileges I would create a user with those privileges only to allow them run without full admin privileges. Otherwise it could, for example, set the proper registry keys to remove the "watchdog" DLL at boot, and then have the machine reboot.

Answer (score 6):

The only safe way to call `SuspendThread` is with a handle to the *current* thread. Suspending any other thread is a bad idea. To get a handle to the current thread, just call `GetCurrentThread`. You can use it pretty much anywhere a thread handle is required. But don't give that handle to another thread — it's a special "pseudo-handle" that *always* means "current thread," no matter which thread has it.

You can use `OpenThread` or `DuplicateHandle` to get a "real" thread handle, but that probably won't get you where you want to go. You won't be able to recognize attempts to suspend your thread or process because the handle *another* program uses to suspend your thread won't necessarily be the same value that you got when you called `OpenThread`. Handles are only meaningful within the process that opened them, and it's possible to acquire multiple handles to the same thing, and that may or may not yield the same value each time.

Instead, call `GetThreadId` to get the ID of the thread being suspended, and then see whether it matches any of your program's thread IDs. Thread IDs uniquely identify threads; handles don't. Likewise for process IDs and handles.

Answer (score 5):

If you have the thread ID, you can get a handle for it using [OpenThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684335%28v=VS.85%29.aspx):

```
HANDLE WINAPI OpenThread(
  __in  DWORD dwDesiredAccess,
  __in  BOOL bInheritHandle,
  __in  DWORD dwThreadId
);
```

Comment: Thanks Steve that was API call that I needed I tried to add SuspendThread Hook to my dll but it is not preventing program to be suspended from utility like Process Explorer.

Comment: I can still prevent program to be closed from task manager Kill Process or any similar task manager like tool hooking TerminateProcess API function, I was hoped that I can do similar with hooking SuspendThread but as much as I can see that utility is not using SuspendThread API call to perform Suspend operation on process. Does anyone have some idea how to prevent application from suspending ???

Comment: If your user has permission to run Process Explorer, there is not much you can do to prevent them killing the process.